# Stylus variable interpolation not working in the animation property?

Tags: css, stylus

I'm having a lot of trouble getting variable interpolation to work consistently in Stylus. Using the version of it currently on CodePen here, no Javascript or anything.

The following Stylus code *looks* to me like it will animate div0 with the animation slide0, animate div1 with the animation slide1, etc etc...

```
for i in (0...4)
  .div{i}
    width: 300px
    animation: slide{i} 1s infinite //Syntax error here

  @keyframes slide{i}
    0%
      letter-spacing: i*3px
    100%
      letter-spacing: 0px
```

...however it just gives a syntax error on the `animation:` line. What doesn't make sense to me is why the *exact same syntax* works when I write it in `.div{i}` and `@keyframes slide{i}`, but not in `animation: slide{i}`.

Here is the error that CodePen gives me, it doesn't seem all that relevant?

```
stylus:4:24
   1| for i in (0...4)
   2|   .div{i}
   3|     width: 300px
   4|     animation: slide{i} 1s infinite
-----------------------------^
   5|   
   6|   @keyframes slide{i}
   7|     0%

expected ":", got "}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you cannot use interpolation inside values of properties or strings. But you can use concatenation:

```
for i in (0...4)
  .div{i}
    width: 300px
    animation: slide + i 1s infinite

@keyframes slide{i}
  0%
    letter-spacing: i*3px
  100%
    letter-spacing: 0px
```

Comment: Oh, that's a weird exception, didn't know interpolation didn't work in properties... Thanks so much!

Comment: Just spent a few hours with this.. Why isn't that possible? :O

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide codepen of your problem, or try `animation-name: slide{i}` separately